# Replicating a spotfire query in powerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, spotfire

I am trying to replicate a query on spotfire in Power BI.

Case when [Dupicates]=1 then sum([nps]) over ([week],[client_name],[survey_type],[category]) else null end.

Can anyone be of help?? I will also appreciate a little explanation.

Comment: Can you please add an example of how you want the report visual to work/look like.

Comment: SO i'm expecting it to return aggregation.
nps sum in every week should return same value.
for example total value in week 1 is 34,567 while week 2 is 24,768
from 27th of Dec 2020 to 2nd of Jan 2021 is week 1 and I expect same value regardless of the date.

Answer (score 0):

```
Measure = calculate (sum(fact[nps]),filter(values(fact[Duplicates]), fact[Duplicates]=1), allexcept(fact,fact[week],fact[client_name], fact[survey_type],fact[category]))
```

Following part ensures the partition
`allexcept(fact,fact[week],fact[client_name], fact[survey_type],fact[category])`

Following part ensures only filtering over dup=1
`filter(values(fact[Duplicates]), fact[Duplicates]=1)`

Comment: Thank you smpa01 for the swift response.
fact only works with measures which (week, client_name, survey_type and category might not be aggregated to work in that place.
any other alternative.
Week, client_name, survey_type and category are not integers or numbers

Comment: Fact is the name of the table. Replace that woth your table name. By `Fact` I was not referring to dax syntax FACT. Also none of the volumns from fact table inside partitioning need to be integer.

Comment: Okay thank you I will get back to you